# Infinte Objects in an Arraylist (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist

im working on a school project.
We have to create a contact list.

So, i created a class generating objects like.

```
    package coursework_q2;


public class Agenda {
    private String name;
    private long phoneNumber;
    private String email;
    private String type;

    public Agenda(){
        name = "";
        phoneNumber = 0;
        email = "";
        type = "";
    }//end of constructor

    @Override
public String toString() {
    return "\nName: " + this.getName() + 
           ", Number: " + this.getPhoneNumber() +
           ", Email: " + this.getEmail() +
           ", Type: " + this.getType();
}



    //setters
    public void setName(String n){
        name = n;
    }//end of setName

    public void setPhoneNumber(long n){
        phoneNumber = n;
    }//end of setPhoneNumber

    public void setEmail(String e){
        email = e;
    }

    public void setType(int t){
        if (t==1){
            type = "Personal";  
        }else{
            type = "Business";
        }
    }//end of setType

    //getters
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }//end of getName

    public long getPhoneNumber(){
        return phoneNumber;
    }//end of getPhoneNumber

    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }//end of getEmail

    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }//end of getType

}//end of class
```

And in my other class i store them in an `arraylist`.

My problem is that i dont know how to create as many contacts as the user wants.

For example:

```
package testcourse;
```

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CourseWork_Q2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Agenda> contacts = new ArrayList();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int check;
    String contact;
    String search;
    Agenda a;
    a = new Agenda();



    int select=0;

    int b=0;

    do {

        System.out.println("1. Add Contact\n2. Edit Contact\n3. Delete Contact\n4. Display All Contacts\n5. Quit");
        System.out.print("Please use the numbers 1-5 to choose an option: ");

        do{//input validation
            check=0;
            if(in.hasNextInt()){
                select = in.nextInt();
                if(1<=select && 5>=select){
                    check=1;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input!\nPlease use the numbers 1-5 to choose an option: ");
                    System.out.println("1. Add Contact\n2. Edit Contact\n3. Delete Contact\n4. Display All Contacts\n5. Quit");
                }//end of if
            }else{
                System.out.println("Invalid Input!\nPlease use the numbers 1-5 to choose an option: ");
                System.out.println("1. Add Contact\n2. Edit Contact\n3. Delete Contact\n4. Display All Contacts\n5. Quit");
                in.next();
            }//end of if
        }while(check==0);


        switch(select){
            case 1: System.out.println("Add Contact");                                                

                    System.out.print("Please enter your contact name: ");
                    a.setName(in.next());
                    System.out.print("\nPlease enter your contact phone-number: ");
                    a.setPhoneNumber(in.nextLong());
                    System.out.print("\nPlease enter your contact email: ");
                    a.setEmail(in.next());
                    System.out.print("\nPlease choose your contact type: ");
                    System.out.println("\n1. Personal\n2. Business");
                    a.setType(in.nextInt());

                    contacts.add(a);
                break;
            case 2: System.out.println("Edit Contact");
                    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the contact you wish to edit: ");
                    search = in.next();

                    for(int i=0; i<contacts.size(); i++){
                            contact = (contacts.get(i)).toString();


                        if(contact.contains("Name: "+search)){
                            System.out.println(contacts.get(i));
                            System.out.println("Please edit the name");
                            a.setName(in.next());
                        }
                    }
                break;
            case 3: System.out.println("Delete Contact");

                break;
            case 4: System.out.println("Display All Contact");
                    for (int i=0; i<contacts.size(); i++){
                    System.out.println(contacts.get(i));
                    }
                break;
            case 5:
                System.exit(5);
                break;
        }//end of switch


    }while (!(check==5));




}//end of main
```

}//end of class

and so on..

How i can do this automatically with my code? So  the user can create as many contacts as he wants?

Thank you!

Comment: Use a looping construct like `while`.

Comment: Yes, but i cant change the variable a1 to a2 and so on.
As a result when the users wants to edit lets say the 5th contact all of them are changing to the edited one.

Comment: Please show ALL relevant code.  As the question stand, it is unclear.

Comment: Probably you want a `Contact` object with `String name`, `int number` and `String email` as fields. And add that object to the agenda arraylist.

Comment: Sorry, this is my 1st question here and im new to java also. im uploading all my code in a sec

Answer (score 3):

Create an `ArrayList` of Agendas:

```
ArrayList<Agenda> contacts = new ArrayList<Agenda>();
```

Every time you want to add a contact, create a new `Agenda`, set the values, and add it to the `ArrayList`

```
Agenda a = new Agenda();
// Do stuff to the agenda/contact, like set names and stuff
contacts.add(a); // Adds the agenda/contact to the ArrayList
```

To edit a contact, all you need to do is retrieve it from the ArrayList with the index of it in the array.

```
int index = 1; // Set it to whichever you need
Agenda a = contacts.get(index);
// Now change whatever is in the agenda
```

To remove a contact, just remove it from the ArrayList using the index.

```
int index = 5;
contacts.remove(index);
```